# CakePHP 4 - How to Save Data Inside foreach loop

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to save datas to mysql database inside a foreach loop but it saves only half of the records. I have tried everything but it doesnt work.

```
                        foreach ($arr_data as $qus) {
                            $data = array(
                                'subject_id' => strval($qus['H']),
                                'question' => nl2br($qus['A']),
                             //   'question_hindi' => translate(nl2br($qus['A'])),
                                'questiontype_id'=>"1",
                                'answer_description' => nl2br($qus['B']),
                             //   'answer_description_hindi' => translate(nl2br($qus['B']))
                            );
                            $savingdata=$this->Questions->newEntity($data,  ['validate' => false]);
                            $this->Questions->save($savingdata);
                            debug($data);
                            $QuesID=$savingdata->id;
                            $answer = array(
                                'question_id' => $QuesID,
                                'answer' => $qus['C'],
                              //  'answer_hindi' => translate($qus['C']),
                                'is_correct' => ($qus['G']=='A') ? 1 : '',
                            );
                          
                            $savingdata=$this->Questions->Answers->newEntity($answer,  ['validate' => false]);
                            $this->Questions->Answers->save($savingdata);
                            $answer = array(
                                'question_id' => $QuesID,
                                'answer' => $qus['D'],
                              //  'answer_hindi' => translate($qus['D']),
                                'is_correct' => ($qus['G']=='B') ? 1 : '',
                            );
                            $savingdata=$this->Questions->Answers->newEntity($answer,  ['validate' => false]);
                            $this->Questions->Answers->save($savingdata);
                            
                            $answer = array(
                                'question_id' => $QuesID,
                                'answer' => $qus['E'],
                             //   'answer_hindi' => translate($qus['E']),
                                'is_correct' => ($qus['G']=='C') ? 1 : '',
                            );
                            $savingdata=$this->Questions->Answers->newEntity($answer,  ['validate' => false]);
                            $this->Questions->Answers->save($savingdata);
                            
                            $answer = array(
                                'question_id' => $QuesID,
                                'answer' => $qus['F'],
                              //  'answer_hindi' => translate($qus['F']),
                                'is_correct' => ($qus['G']=='D') ? 1 : '',
                            );
                            $savingdata=$this->Questions->Answers->newEntity($answer,  ['validate' => false]);
                            $this->Questions->Answers->save($savingdata);
                        }

                        //print_r($records);
                        // Finally we will remove the file from the uploads folder (optional) 
                        unlink($file);
                        $this->Flash->success(__('The questions has been Uploaded'));
                    }
```

I tried debugging $data and all the records shows correctly there. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Have you looked at `$savingdata->getErrors()`? You're calling `save` but never checking return values to see whether those saves worked.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't knew this existed.